# Scala: jaxb or similar?

Tags: xml, scala, jaxb

As a java programmer I'm quite comfortable with using JAXB and similar,
for example to construct object from a XML spec.

I'm sure I can make JAXB work nice in scala, but I wonder
if that is the scala way of doing it, or if there is some
better/smarter way, especially since XML is almost part of
the language / it's internal libraries.

So, given that I want to create a set of object form a XML spec,
what's the recommended way to do this in scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For pure Scala, there is [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/). It generates case classes and parser based on Scala parser combinators. It's still quite young, but if you steer clear of the advanced features of XML Schema it is quite usable.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto on Scalaxb.

Has an issue with '-' in class and field name, turns into "u45" !!

You can fix with this code, to fix in place with this gist:

[PostProcessScalaxb](https://gist.github.com/fancellu/6601111)